# hash values computation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, hash, md5

I am trying to make a program which computes hash values of two dates.The dates are creation date of the file and  the date time when it was last updated.I am getting the same hast values for both in every case even if date of updation and creation are different.My simple aim is to computes the hash values of the two dates and compare them. Please help me with my code . Correct the code or suggest any new code.Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string source, source1;

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo("D:\\file.txt");

            DateTime time1 = info.CreationTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time1);

            DateTime time2 = info.LastAccessTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time2);


            DateTime time3 = info.LastWriteTime;
            Console.WriteLine(time3);

            source = Convert.ToString(time1);
            source1 = Convert.ToString(time3);
            using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
            {
                string hash = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source);
                string hash1 = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source1);
                Console.WriteLine("The MD5 hash of" + time1 + "is:" + hash + ".");
                Console.WriteLine("The MD5 hash of" + time3 + "is:" + hash1 + ".");

                if (VerifyMd5Hash(md5Hash, source, hash))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The hashes are the same.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The hashes are not same.");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }



        static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string source1)
        {

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo("D:\\file.txt");
            DateTime time3 = info.LastWriteTime;

            source1 = Convert.ToString(time3);
            // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. 
            byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source1));

            // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
            // and create a string.
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
            // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            // Return the hexadecimal string. 
            return sBuilder.ToString();
        }

        // Verify a hash against a string. 
        static bool VerifyMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string source1, string hash)
        {
            // Hash the input. 
            string hashOfInput = GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, source1);

            // Create a StringComparer an compare the hashes.
            StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

            if (0 == comparer.Compare(hashOfInput, hash))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have some problem? What is your question?

Comment: are the dates the same?

Comment: hash the file contents, not the dates. If the files are the same, whats the date matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `GetMd5Hash` has a file baked into it that overrides whatever gets passed in. Just kill off the first three lines inside of it

```
static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string source1)
{
    //FileInfo info = new FileInfo("D:\\file.txt");
    //DateTime time3 = info.LastWriteTime;

    //source1 = Convert.ToString(time3);
```

Comment: @user317461 don't forget to mark the answer as correct by using the check

Answer (score 0):

I think ther is an issues in  GetMd5Hash method. independently by your input you compute hash using info.LastWriteTime from same file.

A good approach is to always use input from external call in procedures, to avoid this kind of errors.